# Guzzle returns empty body response, expecting XML

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm using Guzzle 6.5.5 to send a get request and I'm expecting an XML response, but the request returns 200 (OK) with no content. I've tried `$response->getBody()` and `$response->getBody()->getContents()` to no avail. I've also tried setting the 'Accept' header parameter to 'application/xml' but that didn't seem to make a difference.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Without the endpoint specifically, I don't know if we'll be able to help you more. Not every API is designed correctly, so it is possible that a 200 success is still a server 400 or 500 error, just not accounted for

Comment: Same problem here, file_get_contents works properly

Comment: In my case, it was API Server issue, the problem was solved by updating USER_AGENT.